# Why axios returns z_buf_error?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, axios, discord

I am having an issue where axios returns an error

```
cause: Error: unexpected end of file
      at BrotliDecoder.zlibOnError [as onerror] (node:zlib:189:17) {
    errno: -5,
    code: 'Z_BUF_ERROR'
```

I used this function and i don't understand why, though i've tried the same like a month ago

```
export async function getCredentials(req: Request, res: Response) {
  const { code } = req.query;

  const params = new URLSearchParams({
    client_id: process.env.CLIENT_ID as string,
    client_secret: process.env.CLIENT_SECRET as string,
    grant_type: "authorization_code",
    code: code as string,
    redirect_uri: "http://localhost:3000/api/callback",
  });

  const response = await axios.post(
    "https://discord.com/api/oauth2/token",
    params,
    {
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
      },
    }
  );

  res.json(await response.data);
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: It's a new error that is common with Axios version 1.2.1, read on the issues here: https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/5346

Comment: This issue has now been fixed in Axios v1.2.2.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Sorry for the inconvenience, The solution was accept-encoding

```
    const response = await axios.post(
    "https://discord.com/api/oauth2/token",
    params,
    {
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
        "Accept-Encoding": "*",
      },
    }
  );
```

Comment: Thanks! I've been strugling with this for a couple of week now

Comment: Thanks for the example, direct notation `"Accept-Encoding": "gzip,deflate,compress"` helped me.